# IIS server version compatibilty

Tags: iis, master-pages, version

Can we run an application developed for IIS 5.0 to its higher versions i.e. IIS (5.1, 6.0, 7.0)?

Comment: I'm missing the clue to what it has to do with the 'masterpages' tag...

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes, you can.

Somewhat longer answer: I guess you're talking about ASP.NET applications? You'll just want to make sure that you have the right .NET framework version (1.1, 2.0 or 3.5) installed on that server. Framework versions can be installed side-by-side on the same server.

Here's an good article about IIS migration by the IIS guru Bill Staples: [How to Migrate from IIS 6 to IIS 7](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/18/how-to-migrate-from-iis-6-to-iis-7.aspx)